# PDF a partir de una consulta cambiante MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, report

actualmente me encuentro aprendiendo Laravel, a modo de practica quise desarrollar un liquidador de Nomina (un programa que calcula el salario de unos empleados) con 10 empleados de prueba, la parte de los cálculos y su posterior almacenamiento en MySQL ya la pude realizar; en una tabla donde se guardan todos los cálculos y se diferencian por su fecha inicial, lo que significa que del mismo empleado existen muchos registros con diferentes fechas iniciales. Ahora lo que no sé cómo hacer es, crear una vista donde aparezcan las nominas con todos los registros que pertenezcan a la misma fecha inicial (SELECT * FROM `nominas` WHERE `fecha_inicial` = '2019-07-29') e imprimir según mis necesidades los registros de una fecha u otra.

**Nota: ya sé que la librería adecuada es dompdf**

Agradezco cualquier información al respecto.

Comment: haz intentado hacer algo?

Comment: tu pregunta esta medio dispersa, pero te recomendo que hagas un get donde hagas tu consulta y devuelvas un json, y en tu vista lo renderizas con php o con js con un ajax

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente logre hacer esto con Query Scopes.

En la vista:

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/buscar-nomina" method="get">
        <input id="fecha_inicial_opcional" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="date" placeholder="Fecha" aria-label="Search" role="search" name="fecha_inicial_opcional">
        <select id="fecha_inicial" name="fecha_inicial" class="form-control mr-sm-2" aria-label="Search" role="search">
            <option value="" selected></option>
                @foreach($listaDeFechas as $lista)
                <option value="{{$lista->fecha_inicial}}">{{date("d/m/Y",strtotime($lista->fecha_inicial))}}</option>
                @endforeach
        </select>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
        <button style="margin-left: 5px" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="La lista desplegable solo muestra las 10 ultimas nominas. Si necesita imprimir una anterior digite la fecha inicial de dicha dicha nomina en el selector de fechas junto a la lista desplegable">
            &#33;
        </button>
    </form>
```

En el modelo:

```
public function scopeFechaInicial($query, $fecha){
    return $query->where('fecha_inicial', '=' , $fecha);
}
```

luego en el controlador recibo el parametro que el usuario escogio en el form de la vista:\

```
$terminoDeBusqueda = null;

    if ($request->get('fecha_inicial') == ""){
        $terminoDeBusqueda = $request->get('fecha_inicial_opcional');
    } else if ($request->get('fecha_inicial_opcional') == ""){
        $terminoDeBusqueda = $request->get('fecha_inicial');
    }
```

Comment: En StackOverflow es permitido que respondas tu propia pregunta y que marques tu respuesta como aceptada. La idea es que en el futuro, cuando alguien llegue acá con un problema similar, encuentre una respuesta que le ayude a resolverlo. Tu respuesta, sin embargo, no provee de esa ayuda. Por favor lee [answer]. Mientras tanto, esta es una -no respuesta- que debiera eliminarse (a menos que fuese editada).